# Spring Data in Spring 3.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data

As in question. I'm using spring with version 3.0.7:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security Web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.flywaydb/flyway-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>testcontainers</artifactId>
            <version>1.14.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>1.14.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.12</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I'm trying to create model class within @Entity, @Table annotations etc:

```
package main.model.user;

import lombok.*;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;

@Entity
@Getter
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@EqualsAndHashCode
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "user_entity")
public class User implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(
            name = "UUID",
            strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator"
    )
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "phone_number")
    private String phoneNumber;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "body_part_type")
    private BodyPartType favouriteBodyPartType;

    @ElementCollection(targetClass = String.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "permission", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    @Column(name = "permission_name", nullable = false)
    private Set<String> roles = new HashSet<>();

    @Override
    public Collection<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return roles.stream()
                .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

but `Entity, Table, GeneratedValue, GenericGenerator` are marked as red and I cannot import them. I have a question.
Do I have wrong dependencies for spring-data or how does it work? Mabe it does not exist in spring 3.0?

Same for creating `Repositories` (code copied from spring-boot application):

```
package main.user;

import main.exercise.BodyPartType;
import main.model.user.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.UUID;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, UUID> {

    @Query("SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(user) > 0 THEN true ELSE false END FROM User user WHERE user.id =:userID")
    boolean doesAccountExistsWithID(@Param("userID") UUID accountID);

    Optional<User> findByUsername(String name);

    Optional<User> findByEmail(String email);

    Optional<User> findByPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber);

    List<User> findUsersByFavouriteBodyPartType(BodyPartType bodyPartType);
}
```

Is it possible to make something like this in Spring 3.0?

Comment: Check your project's dependency tree to see whether `jakarta.persistence:jakarta.persistence-api` is included or not, because that contains the `javax.persistence` package which includes Entity, Table, GeneratedValue etc. If it is not on the dependency tree, add it to your pom.xml, then you can import those to your class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using these depenencies you can use @Entity, and @Repository.

```
import java.util.UUID;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

@Table(name = "user_entity")
@Entity
public class EntityExample {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(
            name = "UUID",
            strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator"
    )
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private UUID id;

}





<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.main.mytest</groupId>
    <artifactId>email-registration</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

If you dont want to have spring as parent in your pom, then you can add the below dependencies:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.main.mytest</groupId>
    <artifactId>email-registration</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Ive chosen second solution, but do I need spring-context, hibernate-annotations dependencies?

Comment: @miksz1 to run what you have copied from spring-boot, and all those annotations, yes you need those 3 dependencies.